# shinyWidget doesn't run on R Shiny server

Tags: r, flexdashboard, shinywidgets

I have a dashboard that uses shinyWidget package, when I run the dashboard locally, it works fine, however when I put the dashboard on  R shiny server, an error occurs. I narrowed it down and it seems the problem is with the loading of shinyWidget package.
I have an example available [here](https://github.com/azgi/stackoverflow-questions/blob/master/shinyWidget-not-running-onserver.Rmd).
Any suggestions on how to fix load of the library, or what is causing this issue is appreciated.

R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
flexdashboard_0.5.2
shiny_1.5.0
shinyWidgets_0.6.0

Comment: You likely need to update the R version to 4.0+, many of the latest package versions available are only compatible with 4 or higher. An alternative would be try to find some older versions of the packages to run on your older version of R

Comment: It works on my computer, and I uploaded it to my [shinyapps.io](https://www.shinyapps.io) and it worked, and that I think uses R shiny Server.

Comment: Thank you both for looking into this, I found that some of dependencies of the package were not accessible on the shiny server, after installing those the issue was resolved.